# Получение данных из двух таблиц

Tags: sql, select

Помогите реализовать sql запрос select'a. Суть необходимой выборки:
Имеются 2 таблицы:

1. `table1` c полями `name1`, `region`
2. `table2` c полями `name2`, `infocode`, (и еще несколько полей, они не потребуются для запроса)

В поле `infocode` таблицы `table2` первые 2 символа = `region`. 
Я реализовал запрос получения информации из `table2` количества строк с группировкой по `substr(infocode,1,2)`, результирующий вывод получается такой:

```
select substr(infocode,1,2), count(substr(infocode,1,2))
from table2
where (created > '01.01.2016' and created < '30.06.2016')
group by substr(infocode,1,2);
```

----------
| 01 | 1 |
| 02 | 8 |
| 05 | 6 |
| 07 | 5 |
и т.д.

Но мне нужно вывести таким образом:

----------
| 01 | 1 |
| 02 | 8 |
**| 03 | 0 |

| 04 | 0 |**
| 05 | 6 |
**| 06 | 0 |**
| 07 | 5 |

Я так понимаю, нужно брать таблицу `table1` и к ней подставлять значения из предыдущей выборки путем сопоставления `region = substr(infocode,1,2)`, но не получается это реализовать.

Прошу помощи с моим вопросом! Заранее, спасибо.

Comment: покажите ваш запрос.

Comment: select substr(infocode,1,2), count(substr(infocode,1,2)) 
from table2
where (created > '01.01.2016' and created < '30.06.2016')
group by substr(infocode,1,2);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select T1.region, nvl(T2.cnt,0)
  from table1 T1
  left join (
             select substr(infocode,1,2) as region, count(*) as cnt
               from table2
              group by substr(infocode,1,2)
            ) T2
         on T1.region=T2.region
```

Comment: запрос Ваш не работает, выдает "SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: @Mike там видимо еще точка с запятой в конце нужна в его СУБД

Comment: @Mike, Прошу прощения. Рабочая часть запроса приведена выше (спасибо Denis) По-поводу СУБД - Oracle. Все запросы к БД запускаю через Oracle SQL Developer. Правильно отметил Denis, в конце запроса необходима " ; " , но даже при таком исправлении выдается такая де ошибка о неверном завершении SQL-предложения.

Comment: @Mike, Спасибо огромное, все работает!